# Tranfsform does not Work on Safari Mobile

Tags: css

I made this "scroll one by one" effect as you can see here: https://www.polly-livshits.com/ (don't judge the design, it's not final yet haha). But it does not work on my Safari Mobile version, everything is just one below the other.

My code looks like this:

```
.poster{
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 20%;
}  
           
.poster-left {
-ms-transform:translate(-5%, -60%);
-webkit-transform:translate(-5%, -60%);
-moz-transform:translate(-5%, -60%);
-o-transform:translate(-5%, -60%);
-webkit-transform:-webkit-translate(-5%, -60%);
transform:translate(-5%, -60%);
}

<!-- POSTER 1 -->
<div class="poster" style="z-index: 100;"> 
    <div class="poster-left">
        <a href="marriage.php" ><img src="img/p/p.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me again :D

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] in the question itself (include the HTML)

Comment: oh makes sense thx :)